Connecting two different meanings of "degree of freedom"
I have heard at least 2 meanings of "degree of freedom".

The parameter in a t-distribution.

The the number of values in the final calculation of a statistic that are free to vary (like using $n-1$ to estimate sample variance).


Do they have any connection with each other? If so, what is that connection?
This question comes from a comment by @Glen_b in another thread. He said,

There is a connection between the two df's in the case where some random variable (such as a t-statistic) has a t-distribution.


Take a look at the entry for degrees of freedom in https://hbiostat.org/glossary

Hi Frank! (Your books are informative!) That glossary is very thorough, but it doesn't answer my question. Would you be able to make that connection between the 2 concepts?

Have you read our posts about degrees of freedom?

Yes, but I cannot find an answer to my specific question above.

Doesn't your quote of me state there's a connection (answering that bare question affirmatively)? Can you clarify what sort of information you are seeking here?

@Glen_b Yes, it does. I have expanded my question to ask, "If so, what is that connection?" Thank you for pointing out my bad phrasing.

The direct answer is yes, they're connected as your quote states.
Taking a guess at what you're seeking, let's begin with a fact that relates distributions of three random variables (quoting part of the answer to a previous question, but [bracketed] parts are current insertions for added context):

Now one way to obtain such a [$t_\nu$] distribution is to divide a standard normal random variable by the square root of (an independent-of-the-numerator chi-squared divided by its degrees of freedom), i.e. $T=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{{Q}/{\nu}}}$ for $Q\sim \chi^2_\nu$ independent of $Z$. The chi-squared with $\nu$ d.f. can - if $\nu$ is a positive integer - in turn be obtained as a sum squares of independent standard normals. But the t-distribution exists as a mathematical object itself, it doesn't have to arise via this mechanism.

I'll call this "fact 1". As with all the claimed facts here I'll simply state them without proof, but proofs or pointers to proofs can be found in a number of questions on site, as well as in numerous textbooks.
A number of statistics in common use for use as test statistics or for the computation of confidence and prediction intervals can ― given their usual assumptions ― be shown mathematically to be of that specific form. Typically they have an additional scale parameter in the numerator and denominator that cancels out, leaving us with our Z's and Q's.
Such derivations require accounting for dependence (e.g. between data points and their sample mean). While there are $n$ independent data points, estimation of mean-related-parameters has the effect of reducing the dimension when considering residuals that are used in the estimation of variance (e.g. the $n$ residuals from a simple sample mean considered in $n$-space lay in hyperplane of dimension $n-1$; for more complicated linear models the dimension may be further reduced). As such, while a sum of squares of residuals is a sum of squares of $n$ dependent terms, you can in many common cases rewrite it in terms of a sum of squares of independent components in that lower dimension, leaving a result of the form that a multiple of the usual variance estimate has a chi-squared distribution with $n-k$ d.f. where $k$ is the reduction in dimension of residuals arising from estimation of mean parameters.
When the original data values have been drawn independently from normal distributions (and some other conditions hold), you can additionally show that the estimate of error-variance in the denominator and the estimate of the statistic's numerator are independent.
Putting the various facts together - a normal numerator with mean $0$, denominator which is proportional to the square root of (a chi-squared divided by its df) and where the $\sigma$ in the scale of the numerator and denominator cancel, and the numerator and denominator are independent we can use fact 1 to establish that it's distributed as $t$ with the same df-parameter as the chi-squared in the denominator has.
To return to the case you began with in your other question, one where a t-statistic has a t-distribution with $n-1$ d.f., the simplest common case where that occurs is a straight one sample t-test. We'll take the usual assumptions as given.
In that case, the numerator is $\bar{X}-\mu_0$. The denominator is $\sqrt{s^2/n}$. It's possible to show that under the usual assumptions, if $H_0$ is true, the numerator is normal with mean $0$ (and s.d. $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$) and the denominator is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ times the square root of (a chi-squared variate divided by $n-1$), and that the numerator and denominator are independent. Cancelling $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ scale values out  we're left with a statistic which fulfills the conditions we needed to apply fact 1.
Similar results apply for many of the other t-tests in common use, though in some cases you instead have that the t is an approximation and there the d.f. may not have such a direct connection to dimensions spanned by a set of residuals (e.g. the Welch test is one such case).

Sorry, Glen. I'm still really confused. In the other thread, you wrote, "The t-distribution doesn't have an n. At all. Anywhere. It has a degrees-of-freedom parameter, conventionally that's ν." If that is the case, then why does the ν have any connection to this other notion of df (such as the denominator in sample variance)? If I give another name to ν, like "the shape parameter", would there still be any obvious connection between ν and df?

Imagine you're in a place (and possibly time) where uniformed police officer's shirts are required to be blue and cars that are used as taxis are required to be yellow. There's nothing inherent in the category "shirt" or "car" that require them to be any particular colour, and for other purposes they might be other colours, or they might be other colours for no particular purpose. There's nothing about the category "shirt" that makes shirts blue nor about the category "cars" that makes cars yellow. There's no specific connection between "shirt" and "blue" nor between "car" and "yellow"...ctd

ctd... If you use a car(/shirt/ t-distribution) for a specific purpose (taxi/ police-uniform/ one-sample t test), its colour(/colour/df) -which otherwise might be anything- will then be chosen to be yellow(/blue/n-1). But a shirt might be blue for another reason than that specific one, and df might be n-1 for another reason than that specific one.
